# Logout button not moving to right side in ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, bootstrap-4

This is my setting Page

```
 <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
    
       <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>
    
      <ion-row>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-button (click)="logoutAction()"  float-right>Log Out.</ion-button>
      </ion-item>
      </ion-row>
      </ion-toolbar>          
     
    </ion-header>
             
    <ion-content>
     
        ..other code
     
    </ion-content>
```

This looks like  below

[image]

I need to float right in settings header. Is it possible to move right side..pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have tried this to use `slot`.

```html
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Settings<ion-title>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-button (click)="logoutAction()" slot="end">Log Out.</ion-button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Will output

```
SETTINGS
                                    LOG OUT.
```

if you don't want a line in between, you can skip the `ion-item`.

```html
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Settings<ion-title>
    <ion-button (click)="logoutAction()" slot="end">Log Out.</ion-button>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Will output

```
SETTINGS                            LOG OUT.
```

Comment: Is <ion-row>
      <ion-item> i s neccessary?

Comment: @Ajt Absolutely not, `ion-row` must be used inside `ion-grid`: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/row

Comment: Thanks and last query..ion-item is used for?

Comment: For very various things. No concrete answer for this one. I will add more to my answer.